# How to return propertie from sub array object with react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a react native app. And I try to show the name and image on a card.

So this is the service:

```
export const fetchSubCategoryData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.68:8000/api/categories/2", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }

        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("There was a problem with the fetch operation:", error);
        throw error;
    }
};

export const subCategoryTransform = ({ results = [] }) => {
    const mappedResults = results.map((subcategories) => {
        subcategories.images = subcategories.images;
        return {
            ...subcategories,
            name: subcategories.name,
        };
    });

    return mappedResults;
};
```

the context:

```
export const CategoryContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [categoryList, setCategoryList] = useState([]);
    const [subCategoryList, setSubCategoryList] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [] = useState([]);

    const retrieveSubCategories = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetchSubCategoryData()
                .then(subCategoryTransform)
                .then((results) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setSubCategoryList([results]);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setError(err);
                });
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveCategories();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveSubCategories();
    }, []);

    return (
        <CategoryContext.Provider
            value={{
                categoryList,
                subCategoryList,
                loading,
                error,
            }}>
            {children}
        </CategoryContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

And the component where I want to show the name and the image:

```
export const SubCategoryScreen = () => {
    const { subCategoryList } = useContext(CategoryContext);

    return (
        <SafeArea>
            <CategoryList
                data={subCategoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    console.log(item.subcategories);
                    return (
                        <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                            <CategoryInfoCard category={item.subcategories} />
                        </Spacer>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.subcategories}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

And the api call of http://192.168.1.68:8000/api/categories/2/ looks:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "vogels",
    "description": "vogels",
    "legislation": "",
    "review": "",
    "eaza": "",
    "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/photos/categories/birds.png",
    "animals": [],
    "subcategories": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "roofvogels",
            "description": "roofvogels",
            "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/photos/categories/predator_ETI4KPC.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "parkieten",
            "description": "parkieten",
            "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/photos/categories/predator_gqLXVoK.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "category": null
}
```

And then I want to show the name and images of the subcategories. So in this case:
roofvogels and parkieten.

But I get this error:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.%s%s See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.%s, 

Check the render method of `VirtualizedList`., , 
CellRenderer@http://192.168.1.68:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:82071:36
    in VirtualizedList (created by FlatList)
```

Question: How to return the name and images of the subcategories object?

I try this:

```
export const SubCategoryScreen = () => {
    const { subCategoryList } = useContext(CategoryContext);

    return (
        <SafeArea>
            <CategoryList
                data={subCategoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    console.log(item.subcategories);
                    return (
                        <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                            <CategoryInfoCard category={item.subcategories} />
                        </Spacer>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

But still:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.%s%s See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.%s, 

Check the render method of `VirtualizedList`., , 
CellRenderer@http://192.168.1.68:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:82071:36
    in VirtualizedList (created by FlatList)
```

And so this is the component when the app is first time loading. This is the main screen. And from there the user can navigate to a subcategorie card:

```
import { ActivityIndicator, MD2Colors } from "react-native-paper";
import { FlatList, Pressable, SafeAreaView, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import React, { useContext } from "react";

import { CategoryContext } from "../../../services/category/category.context";
import { CategoryInfoCard } from "../components/category-info-card.component";
import { MD3LightTheme as DefaultTheme } from "react-native-paper";
import { Search } from "../components/search.component";
import { Spacer } from "../../../components/spacer/spacer.component";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import styled from "styled-components/native";

const SafeArea = styled(SafeAreaView)`
    flex: 1;
    ${StatusBar.currentHeight && `margin-top: ${StatusBar.currentHeight}px`};
`;

export const CategoryList = styled(FlatList).attrs({
    contentContainerStyle: {
        padding: 16,
    },
})``;

const Loading = styled(ActivityIndicator)`
    margin-left: -25px;
`;
const LoadingContainer = styled.View`
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
`;

export const CategoryScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { loading, error, categoryList } = useContext(CategoryContext);
    return (
        <SafeArea>
            {loading && (
                <LoadingContainer>
                    <ActivityIndicator animating={true} color={MD2Colors.green200} />
                </LoadingContainer>
            )}
            <Search />
            <CategoryList
                data={categoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("groepen", { subcategories: item.id })}>
                            <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                                <CategoryInfoCard category={item} />
                            </Spacer>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

If I do this:

```
const retrieveSubCategories = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetchSubCategoryData()
                //.then(subCategoryTransform)
                .then((results) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setSubCategoryList([results]);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setError(err);
                });
        });
    };
```

Then I see in the console.log:

```
return (
        <SafeArea>
            <CategoryList
                data={subCategoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    console.log("SUBCATEGORES", item.subcategories);
                    return (
                        <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                            <CategoryInfoCard category={item.subcategories} />
                        </Spacer>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
```

```
SUBCATEGORES Array [
  Object {
    "description": "roofvogels",
    "id": 3,
    "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/photos/categories/predator_ETI4KPC.jpg",
    "name": "roofvogels",
  },
  Object {
    "description": "parkieten",
    "id": 5,
    "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/photos/categories/predator_gqLXVoK.jpg",
    "name": "parkieten",
  },
]
```

So this is correct.

This is the complete service:

```
export const fetchCategoryData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.68:8000/api/categories/main_groups/", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }

        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("There was a problem with the fetch operation:", error);
        throw error;
    }
};

export const fetchSubCategoryData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.68:8000/api/categories/2", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }

        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("There was a problem with the fetch operation:", error);
        throw error;
    }
};

export const categoryTransform = ({ results = [] }) => {
    const mappedResults = results.map((categoryList) => {
        categoryList.images = categoryList.images;
        return {
            ...categoryList,
            name: categoryList.name,
        };
    });

    return mappedResults;
};

export const subCategoryTransform = ({ results = [] }) => {
    const mappedResults = results.map((subcategories) => {
        subcategories.subcategories.images = subcategories.subcategories.images;
        return {
            ...subcategories,
            name: subcategories.name,
        };
    });

    return mappedResults;
};
```

I have one main screen with url:

> http://192.168.1.68:8000/api/categories/main_groups/

And from here you can navigate to a subcategory:

subscreen with url:

> http://192.168.1.68:8000/api/categories/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an object as a key - it should be a string. In your CategoryList, you have

```
keyExtractor={(item) => item.subcategories}
```

Try using

```
keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
```

Comment: #Abe.Thank you, but still I get that error

Comment: #Abe. SUBCATEGORES undefined , console.log("SUBCATEGORES", item.subcategories);

Comment: Where are you using a FlatList in your code? Can you show that please?

Comment: There are some confusing parts in your code - where is `retrieveCategories` defined? Are you sure you're not confusing categories and subcategories? If you're using `data={subCategoryList}`, you can't use `category={item.subcategories}`, because the subcategory won't have that property.

Comment: #Abe. I edit the post. I hope it is more clear now